# Old paperback novel from the 1980s about a man imprisoned on a beach by ...Them

Tags: story-identification, novel

It was obviously expanded from a (not very good) short story, but I am trying to track down one of those old disposable paperback science fiction novels.

This one involves a man trapped in a beachside resort where he and others spend their time in aimless holiday type activities. At one far end of the beach is a talking Sphinx. It has overtones of the 1960s show The Prisoner and features a far too long interpolation involving the Marx Brothers. It ends with the protagonist awakening from one dream world into an apparently real world where an alien race who resemble an abstract angelic choir have contacted the Earth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like *Freedom Beach* by James Patrick Kelly and John Kessel, which I have read. ISFDB notes that the novel was based on [previously published material](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?836) including a Marx Brothers related story. The US cover is a Sphinx.

[image: Front cover of the book, showing the Sphinx]

There is a discussion of the novel in context [here](https://gapingblackbird.wordpress.com/2017/11/29/freedom-beach-by-james-patrick-kelly-and-john-kessel/) plus the original Kirkus Reviews capsule is available on the Goodreads page. HTH

> Freedom Beach (1985), a collaborative effort from James Patrick Kelly and John Kessel, splits most of its pages between the titular resort and extended dream sequences of the protagonist. Freedom Beach is some sort of strange purgatory where the characters are cared for, encouraged to fritter away their time, but forbidden to write anything down or make serious attempts at retaining memories. Guests, or more appropriately – patients, lead a Brave New World-type of existence, complete with a daily drug they call “communion,” nude volleyball games and abandonment of their past identities. A hidden group called “the dreamers” are in charge of this place and the patients’ therapy, interacting with them through drugs, robots and speaker-equipped statues.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you perhaps [edit] your answer to include some relevant quotes or passages from the blog post you linked? Unfortunately links sometimes go stale, so it's best to include the essential parts in your answer and have the link as a reference

Comment: Yes, this is definitely it. I have managed to track down a copy of the book and it matches the description exactly.